# Android Navigation Bar overlaying my view

Tags: android, overlay, navigationbar

I have an issue with Android Navigation Bar on devices like Nexus etc. Simply at all devices, which do not have the hardware menu button.

Let me explain the issue in more details.

I have an application where there are 3 parts. Content, ActionBar and bottom panel with a SeekBar.

[image]

ActionBar and bottom panel with a SeekBar are overlaying the content. Everytime I click on the content the ActionBar and bottom panel with a SeekBar disappear. Which works exactly the way it has to work. Here is a fragment of a code I use for hiding system UI:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {                
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
} else {                
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    actionBar.hide();
}
findViewById(R.id.read_book_bottom_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In `onCreate` method of my activity, I have this piece of code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {            
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);          
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);   
}
```

However, when I launch the application on devices with Android Navigation Bar, there is a problem with displaying the bottom panel with a SeekBar. Simply, the Android Navigation Bar overlays the bottom panel with a SeekBar. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

But everytime I click on the content, the Android Navigation Bar disappears along with the ActionBar and the bottom panel with the SeekBar. So, the issue is, that everytime somebody would like to use the bottom panel with the SeekBar on devices like NEXUS, he/she would not be able to use it, because it's hidden under the Android Navigation Bar.

Could anybody help me with solving this issue? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I solved it with attribute `fitsSystemWindows = true`.

Comment: In addition to this, try using padding instead of margin. May help in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

That may also happen when you set `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:layout_marginTop="30dp"`
I fixed similar issue by seting `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` instead. Then marginTop works as assumed.