# Android Lollipop navigation bar overlays activity view

Tags: android

the navigation bar is overlaying my activity view on the bottom. Same issue like here: [Android Navigation Bar overlaying my view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471113/android-navigation-bar-overlaying-my-view)

The issue seems to happen only on Android Lollipop. On my Moto G with KitKat 4.4.4. i don't have this issue. I don't know why this problem is only related to Lollipop.

My problem is, with the solution @ps-glass postet is not working for me somehow setting `fitsSystemWindow = true`. I tried it with the theme or with the layout file directly, nothing worked for me so far.

Here is an image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5g_MttTC7ZIQzNfS3Y2dVFKSFk/view?usp=sharing

You can only see a bit of the text, the rest is overlaid by the navigation bar.

Comment: I found another solution using a library (Part 4) https://mindofaandroiddev.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/making-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-transparent-with-a-listview-on-android-4-4-kitkat/ But i don't want to use a library for this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android L ActionBarActivity using Feinstein SldingMenu and AppCompat v21 is cut off at bottom of the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781023/android-l-actionbaractivity-using-feinstein-sldingmenu-and-appcompat-v21-is-cut)

Comment: This is a duplicate. See my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28459582/969880

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found out that this problem is related to a library we are using:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
and other people have this problem too after they updated their AppCompat to v21.

Some solutions were posted here https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680 and another one here [The getDecorView method return view include navigation bar view on lollipop？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165690/the-getdecorview-method-return-view-include-navigation-bar-view-on-lollipop/27535016#27535016)

The Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/users/715451/saulobrito is working for me now and it is the easiest way i think.

```
<style name="Theme" parent="FrameworkRoot.Theme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

I put this code snippet to a my theme in the `res/values-v21` folder.

Comment: Thank you soo much man. I was stuck in this bug for days. I thought this is a bug in Lollipop.

Comment: Yes, this is because it's not any solution. What if I need color status bar?